# PHP regex to simplify webmail referrer addresses?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to aggregate stats on referrers to my site, to give me a simple display of top referrers.  Unfortunately referrer data is untrustworthy, and often dirty, so I'm just trying to make a good faith attempt to get something like usable data.

I've already filtered bad urls, and used url_parts to get the host portion of each url.  I've then stripped common aliased subdomains, and social media url-shorteners, like t.co or fb.me

The big issue that remains is webmail.  many webmail providers shunt their users to a sub-sub domain, as soon as they log in, for load-balancing.  This is easy to filter, for mail services like yahoo, as they are all something.something.mail.yahoo.com, so I can just check if the third from last segment is "mail" or a similar subdomain, and strip all previous segments.

But now I am left with the hard cases, subdomains like:

```
webmaila (like webmaila.juno.com)
email16  (like email16.secureserver.net)
webmailb (like webmailb.netzero.net)
```

I need to find entries that start with 'mail', 'webmail', 'email', or 'mailbox', followed by any string, and strip the string, leaving me with just the appropriate prefix.

How can I do that?

Comment: `preg_replace('/^[^.]*mail[^.]*\./','',$host);`

Comment: @JonathanKuhn That just blanks all subdomains that include 'mail' as a substring... I need to preserve the prefixes, and I'd prefer to not kill legit subdomains like airmail.dhl.com

Answer (score 0):

```
echo preg_replace('#^(webmaila|email16|webmailb)(.+)?#', '$1', $string);
```

Comment: This solution is close, but only works on the specific examples I gave, not on the more universal problem I described... I tried to modify it to work with my needs, and got into trouble... I'm not sure why this doesn't work: `$refHostParts[0] = preg_replace('/^(mailbox|mail|webmail|email)(.+)?/', '$1', $maybe_mail_str);`

Comment: I take it back, my modified form works as expected... I simply had another error